# Including header files in VS2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, header-files

How do you include header files from top-level and sub-directories in c++?

Comment: can you clarify the question? you want to know where to specify additional header paths in visual studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#include "sub/some_header.h"`

`#include "../other_header.h"`

Answer (score 0):

From the include directory? I guess you meant like:

`#include <dir\header.h>`

Comment: if the header file is in the include directory use greater than and less than symbols (<>), if it's on the project directory or solution, use double quotations ("").

Comment: I'm begging you, please don't use backslashes... I know you think you're *never* going to port your application... but you might one day, and it will be a huge pain in the arse to change all your backslashed includes to forward slashes. VS will gladly use forward slashes, e.g. #include <dir/header.h>